# How to modify state transition in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any way to modify a custom state to be only available for a certain user groups and state?

For example I have 2 custom states:

- QA PR Approved
- Released To QA

For build administrators, the only available state is Released To QA and that state will only be available if the work item's state is QA PR Approved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to modify a custom state to be only available for a
>   certain user groups and state?

As of today, unfortunately, this haven't been supported to achieve.

We provided one similar feature and it can make the [fields viewable to some specific groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops), but not the value of fields.

A good news is we has took such [feature suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365830/allow-specifying-state-transitions-when-using-inhe.html) into our develop roadmap. And there has one develop task in our backlog to track this feature. You can keep following on that suggestion link so that you can get the latest develop news we update.

[image]

If everything goes well, I believe this feature can be available in Azure devops soon. BUT, until now, our Azure Devops can not satisfied your demand.

Comment: @DudesvilleHurynnx. It's welcome! Hope our team could give this feature to public soon.  Any puzzle still exists on this? Free to let me know, I would try to give you the reply with my best.